# SSIS 2012 Colors

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, themes, ssis-2012

We just upgraded to SQL Server 2012 and SSIS 2012, being used to 2008 the colors is a huge jump and can hardly see when something is disabled in your SSIS package. I know you can change the Color theme to Dark or Blue but it still dont not help much.

Any idea how we can modify the colors to look more like it did in 2008?

Answer (score 0):

The look and feel of 2012 Data tool is different from than that of 2008 Visual studio/BIDS.
As these are different product (latest is data tools and the oldest is BIDS/Visual studio)
we can not change the theme exactly as the previous version :)

Answer (score 0):

I myself am looking, so far I discovered that they did take this into account in VS 2013.  See [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3184305-bring-back-full-color-icons-to-visual-studio-2012).  However, VS 2013 seems only to support SQL Server 2014 tools, so we have not been able to upgrade.

There seems to be a [Color Theme Editor tool for Visual Studio 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05), but finding what they called task boxes, for example, if I want to fix the tasks so that when you disable them you can actually tell, well, this seems near to impossible!  I wish someone would create a custom scheme and share it so we could all use it